# Javascript formatting array of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array...

```
var dates = [{"date_play":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-24 00:00:00"}];
```

How can i format that date to produce like this:

```
var newDates = ['08-22-2016','08-23-2016','08-24-2016'];
```

Comment: You can also make use of moment.js for all date and time related things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you already have text, you can just manipulate the text.

```js
var dates = [{"date_play":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-24 00:00:00"}];

var newDates = [];
$.each(dates,function(i,obj){
    newDates.push(obj['date_play'].replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*$/,'$2-$3-$1'));
});
console.log(newDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or:

```js
var dates = [{"date_play":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-24 00:00:00"}];

var newDates = [];
dates.forEach(function(obj){
    newDates.push(obj['date_play'].replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*$/,'$2-$3-$1'));
});
console.log(newDates);
```

Or:

```js
var dates = [{"date_play":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-24 00:00:00"}];

var newDates = dates.map(function(obj){
    return obj['date_play'].replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*$/,'$2-$3-$1');
});
console.log(newDates);
```

Or:

```js
var dates = [{"date_play":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},{"date_play":"2016-08-24 00:00:00"}];

var newDates = dates.map(function(obj){
    var tmp = obj['date_play'].split(/[- ]/,3);
    return tmp[1] + '-' + tmp[2] + '-' + tmp[0];
});
console.log(newDates);
```

**Explaining the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) regular expression:**
The `replace()`, in this case, is being used with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (regular expression) which uses three [capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) to briefly hold the month, day and year, and then replace the string with just the contents of the capture groups separated by `-` characters, but in a different order (month-day-year).

```
replace(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*$/,'$2-$3-$1')
         │ ││ ││ │ │ ││ │ │ │││││    │  │  └───Replace with capture group #1 (year)
         │ │┕┯┙│ │ │ ││ │ │ │││││    │  └──────Replace with capture group #3 (day)
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ │ │ │││││    └─────────Replace with capture group #2 (month)
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ │ │ ││││└────────────── $   = The end of the string (not really needed here)
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ │ │ │││└─────────────── *   = Repeat the previous character, or group, 0 up to as many times as possible ( .* matches the rest of the string)
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ │ │ ││└──────────────── .   = Any character
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ │ │ │└───────────────── )   = End capture group #3 (which is 2 digits, the day)
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ │ │ └────────────────── \d  = A digit
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ │ └──────────────────── \d  = A digit
         │ │ │ │ │ │ ││ └────────────────────── (   = Begin capture group #3
         │ │ │ │ │ │ │└──────────────────────── )   = End capture group #2 (which is 2 digits, the month)
         │ │ │ │ │ │ └───────────────────────── \d  = A digit
         │ │ │ │ │ └─────────────────────────── \d  = A digit
         │ │ │ │ └───────────────────────────── (   = Begin capture group #3
         │ │ │ └─────────────────────────────── )   = End capture group #1 (which is 4 digits, the year)
         │ │ └───────────────────────────────── {4} = Repeat the previous character, or group, exactly 4 times (4 digits, the year)
         │ └─────────────────────────────────── \d  = A digit
         └───────────────────────────────────── (   = Begin capture group #1

All of the '-' characters are just '-' characters: part of the old string, or part
of the replacement.
```

Comment: Thanks of giving more choices. ill use the 4th example.

Comment: @Jefsama, Sorry. My bad. I was still editing and added one (the `forEach` @ #2. I'm assuming you mean the one that is now fourth (`map` and `split`).

Comment: Yeah i edit. Just one thing, can you elaborate me whats happening in the `replace` ? coz i find it complicated when look hehe

Comment: @Jefsama, I have added an explanation of the regular expression being used with the `replace()`. Does that make it a bit more understandable?

Comment: Appreciated. Thank very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newDates = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
       var date = new Date(item.date_play);
       newDates.push((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery, or a Date parser; all you need is to break up the string.

It's important not to convert it to a date object because when you do, it'll enforce timezones and the object may even misrepresent your day (e.g., `2016-08-22` may become `8-21-2016`) due to the timezone shift.

```js
let dates = [
  {"date_play":"2016-08-22 00:00:00"},
  {"date_play":"2016-08-23 00:00:00"},
  {"date_play":"2016-08-24 00:00:00"}
];
let newDates = dates.map(obj=>{
  let dt = obj.date_play.split(' ')[0].split('-');
  return [dt[1],dt[2],dt[0]].join('-');
});
```

Because it looks like your data input is uniform, either adjust the source, or just rearrange your string content.